# Add Validation Error

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, feedcomment

I need to throw an error to the user when he tries to post/comment on case whose status is Closed - Resolved. I've tried to implement that and when I try to comment on a case the trigger is failing with the below error -

```
FeedCommentTriggerHandler: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors Trigger.FeedCommentTriggerHandler: line 30, column 1
```

Here is my trigger-

```
trigger FeedCommentTriggerHandler on FeedComment (after insert) { // GET LIST OF PARENT IDS
List<Id> ParentIds = new List<Id>();
for(FeedComment f:Trigger.new)ParentIds.add(f.ParentId);
// CREATE LIST OF FEEDITEM FOR CREATEDBY TO BE POPULATED
List<FeedComment> feedItems = new List<FeedComment>([SELECT Id,FeedItemId,CreatedById,CreatedDate,CreatedBy.Profile.UserType,CreatedBy.Profile.Name,ParentId,CommentType FROM FeedComment WHERE Id in :Trigger.newMap.keyset()]);

// INIT A MAP OF RELATED CASES WITH PARENT IDS
Map<Id,Case> relatedCases = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT id,Status,isClosed, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id in :ParentIds ]);

// UPDATE CASE STATUS OF EACH CUSTOMER FEED RELATED CASE TO OPEN
for(FeedComment feed:feedItems)
{
    // IF FEED IS  CREATED BY customers
    System.debug('FeedCommentTriggerHandler: '+feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name+' '+feed.ParentId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName()+' '+feed.CommentType);
    if( (feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name =='B2B Customer Community Login' || feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name == 'B2B Customer Community User' || feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name == 'B2B Account Manager User' || feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name == 'B2B Account Manager Login') && (relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).status == 'Pending' || relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).status == 'Waiting Internally' ) && feed.ParentId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() =='Case')
    {            
        // SET CASE TO in progess 
        
        relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).Pending_Date_Time__c = null;
        relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).Status = 'In Progress';
        relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).Sub_Status__c = '';
        relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).Feed_Last_Modified_Date__c=feed.CreatedDate;  
        
            }
    else if( (feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name =='B2B Customer Community Login' || feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name =='System Administrator' ||  feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name == 'B2B Customer Community User' || feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name == 'B2B Account Manager User' || feed.CreatedBy.Profile.Name == 'B2B Account Manager Login') && (relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).status == 'Closed - Resolved') && feed.ParentId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() =='Case')

    {
        Feed.addError('Comments/Post not allowed on Resolved/Closed Cases');
    }
    else if(feed.ParentId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() =='Case')
    {
        relatedCases.get(feed.ParentId).Feed_Last_Modified_Date__c=feed.CreatedDate;
        
    } 
    
}

if(relatedCases.values().size()>0)update relatedCases.values();}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`addError()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError) documentation states (emphasis mine):

> Marks **a trigger record** with a custom error message and prevents any DML operation from occurring.

The [Trigger Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm) one states (emphasis mine):

> Triggers can be used to prevent DML operations from occurring by calling the addError() method on a record or field. **When used on Trigger.new records** in insert and update triggers, and on Trigger.old records in delete triggers, the custom error message is displayed in the application interface and logged.

The issue is that you're calling `addError()` on an **instance** of SObject that is not a trigger record **instance**.
Indeed you retrieved those FeedComment via SOQL and even if they are related to the same db records, they are not the same instances.
You should add the error on `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap` records.

Change this line

```
Feed.addError('Comments/Post not allowed on Resolved/Closed Cases');
```

to

```
FeedComment triggerFeed = Trigger.newMap.get(feed.Id);
triggerFeed.addError('Comments/Post not allowed on Resolved/Closed Cases');
```

By the way, you can also change

```
List<FeedComment> feedItems = new List<FeedComment>([SELECT Id,FeedItemId,CreatedById,CreatedDate,CreatedBy.Profile.UserType,CreatedBy.Profile.Name,ParentId,CommentType FROM FeedComment WHERE Id in :Trigger.newMap.keyset()]);
```

to

```
List<FeedComment> feedItems = [SELECT Id,FeedItemId,CreatedById,CreatedDate,CreatedBy.Profile.UserType,CreatedBy.Profile.Name,ParentId,CommentType FROM FeedComment WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];
```

That SOQL already returns a list.

Please also consider moving the logic in an handler class.